# Copy to clipboard like Google Drive does

Tags: html, copy, clipboard

OK I know that JavaScript cannot put anything in my clipboard, but when you visit Google Drive from webkit browser (without flash) and then try to share some file, you have an option to generate link and after that 'copy to clipboard' button appears that just works without flash. Any ideas how it's implemented? I'd really like to copy this solution to my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ZeroClipboard from [gitHub](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard). This is a jQuery script which helps to copy data to clipboard. Use of this script has been shown [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/jquery-copy-clipboard)

Comment: My point was not to use flash to achieve this, google somehow did it in webkit browsers and I want to copy this solution to my webapp.